# MultiUserChatLight Group Message Listener

Tags: android, smack, multiuserchat, xmpppy

Developing a Chat APP Group function using MucLight XEP  with smack library 
,the problem  is I m able to send the message  to group successfully but when its come to message listening I get confused,in smack library  we have

```
 multiUserChatLight.addMessageListener (new MessageListener ( ) {
                @Override
                public void processMessage(Message message) {

                }
            });
```

But its group Specific listener , means Its only listen to multiuserchatlight reference group, which some how not what  I need,because every time whenever I reconnected with the chat server I need to register this listener  against every group in which I involved , which is not good in opinion .
the other approach  is to register `packetlistener`  which is also little problematic with some cases like  as member  of group I received the message  which I send into the  group ,

So there is any alternative?

Can some one tell me where i am wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

whenever you connected with server and authenticated you need to register always message listener. i have done using StanzaListener to add MucLight listener.

```
  public RegisterXmppListener registerXmppListener;

  public void registerMessageListener(){
    debugLog("registerMessageListener");
    if(mStanzaListener !=null)
        connection.removeSyncStanzaListener(mStanzaListener);

    StanzaTypeFilter filter = new StanzaTypeFilter(Message.class);

    mStanzaListener=new StanzaListener() {
        @Override
        public void processStanza(Stanza stanza) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException, InterruptedException {
            if(registerXmppListener!=null) {
                registerXmppListener.onMessageReceived(stanza);
            }
        }
    };
    connection.addSyncStanzaListener(mStanzaListener, filter);
}
```

registerMessageListener register when you have authenticated with server.